# Como proceder quando a resposta aceite não esta em Português?

Tags: debate

O titulo e explicativo o suficiente, mas fiquei com duvidas relativamente a esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38433/8113).

O OP agradeceu a resposta e aceitou-a, no entanto ela continua em inglês. Como devemos proceder nestes casos?

E relativamente ao ponto de vista de quem pergunta, devemos aceitar mesmo que a resposta não esteja em Português?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Creio que traduzir seja a melhor saída, além de alertar o autor da resposta quando possível.

O ideal seria o próprio OP solicitar a tradução antes de aceitá-la, mas não temos controle sobre isso.

Caso você (ou qualquer usuário) não queira ou não possa fazer a tradução por qualquer motivo, sinalize, assim os demais usuários podem atuar de alguma forma.

Comment: Não entendo porque meu comentário foi removido da resposta... Teve alguma sinalização?

Comment: @brasofilo Eu limpei os comentários em Inglês. Pelo que me lembro, a notificação para o usuário ainda será exibida, mesmo que ele não tenha visto ainda.

Comment: Bom, não acho produtivo, teve alguém do mundo SOen que veio aqui querer participar, uma explicação (na língua de origem) abaixo do post dá contexto ao assunto/problema.

Comment: @brasofilo Além do próprio usuário do SOen, você acha o comentário em Inglês relevante para quem vai acessar o site posteriormente?

Comment: Enquanto a resposta tiver aquele **[original]** ou enquanto o autor não dê um feedback, sim, deixaria o comentário por um tempo mais. O evento é muito recente, não acho que o comentário seja obsoleto nem não construtivo.

Comment: @brasofilo Ok, restaurei seu comentário e vou aguardar para ver se o autor se manifesta.